# Evento touchstart en ocasiones no se lanza [HTML + JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, eventos, touch

Tengo problemas con eventos touch de javascript en navegadores móviles. 
Normalmente funciona como es de esperar, pero hay ocasiones en las se accede a dicha página realizando desplazamientos y taps sobre la pantalla, mientras se carga "la única manera, con la que siempre logro reproducirlo". Esto hace que no se lancen ninguno de los eventos touch y sea imposible realizar los trazos en el canvas.

He simplificado bastante el código, para evitar interferencias con el resto de código de la página.

***index.php***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" /> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />   
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="location.href='/firmar.php'"><h1>ejemplo firma1</h1></button>    
</body>
</html>
```

***firmar.php*** solicita una firma que se capta mediante un canvas.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" /> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />        

        <script type="text/javascript">
        var ongoingTouches = []; 

        function handleStart(evt) {
          evt.preventDefault();
          var el = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
          var ctx = el.getContext("2d");
          var touches = evt.changedTouches;

          for (var i = 0; i < touches.length; i++) {
            ongoingTouches.push(copyTouch(touches[i]));
            var color = colorForTouch(touches[i]);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(touches[i].pageX, touches[i].pageY, 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);  // a circle at the start
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fill();
          }
        } 

        function handleMove(evt) {
          evt.preventDefault();
          var el = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
          var ctx = el.getContext("2d");
          var touches = evt.changedTouches;

          for (var i = 0; i < touches.length; i++) {
            var color = colorForTouch(touches[i]);
            var idx = ongoingTouchIndexById(touches[i].identifier);

            if (idx >= 0) {
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.moveTo(ongoingTouches[idx].pageX, ongoingTouches[idx].pageY);
              ctx.lineTo(touches[i].pageX, touches[i].pageY);
              ctx.lineWidth = 4;
              ctx.strokeStyle = color;
              ctx.stroke();

              ongoingTouches.splice(idx, 1, copyTouch(touches[i]));  // swap in the new touch record      
            }
          }
        } 

        function handleEnd(evt) {
          evt.preventDefault();
          var el = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
          var ctx = el.getContext("2d");
          var touches = evt.changedTouches;

          for (var i = 0; i < touches.length; i++) {
            var color = colorForTouch(touches[i]);
            var idx = ongoingTouchIndexById(touches[i].identifier);

            if (idx >= 0) {
              ctx.lineWidth = 4;
              ctx.fillStyle = color;
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.moveTo(ongoingTouches[idx].pageX, ongoingTouches[idx].pageY);
              ctx.lineTo(touches[i].pageX, touches[i].pageY);
              ctx.fillRect(touches[i].pageX - 4, touches[i].pageY - 4, 8, 8);  // and a square at the end
              ongoingTouches.splice(idx, 1);  // remove it; we're done
            } 
          }
        } 

        function handleCancel(evt) {
          evt.preventDefault();
          var touches = evt.changedTouches;

          for (var i = 0; i < touches.length; i++) {
            var idx = ongoingTouchIndexById(touches[i].identifier);
            ongoingTouches.splice(idx, 1);  // remove it; we're done
          }
        } 

        function colorForTouch(touch) {
          var r = touch.identifier % 16;
          var g = Math.floor(touch.identifier / 3) % 16;
          var b = Math.floor(touch.identifier / 7) % 16;
          r = r.toString(16); // make it a hex digit
          g = g.toString(16); // make it a hex digit
          b = b.toString(16); // make it a hex digit
          var color = "#" + r + g + b;
          return color;
        } 

        function copyTouch(touch) {
          return { identifier: touch.identifier, pageX: touch.pageX, pageY: touch.pageY };
        } 

        function ongoingTouchIndexById(idToFind) {
          for (var i = 0; i < ongoingTouches.length; i++) {
            var id = ongoingTouches[i].identifier;

            if (id == idToFind) {
              return i;
            }
          }
          return -1;    // not found
        } 

        function startup() {
          var el = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
          el.addEventListener("touchstart", handleStart, false);
          el.addEventListener("touchend", handleEnd, false);
          el.addEventListener("touchcancel", handleCancel, false);
          el.addEventListener("touchmove", handleMove, false);

        } 
        </script>

        <style>
        body{
            padding:0;
            margin:0
        }

        svg:not(:root){
            display:block
        }
        .playable-code{
            background-color:#f4f7f8;
            border:none;
            border-left:6px solid #558abb;
            border-width:medium medium medium 6px;
            color:#4d4e53;
            height:100px;
            width:90%;
            padding:10px 10px 0
        }
        .playable-canvas{
            border:1px solid #4d4e53;
            border-radius:2px
        }
        .playable-buttons{
            text-align:right;
            /*width:90%;*/
            padding:5px 10px 5px 26px
        }        
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="startup()">

      <canvas id="canvas" width="300px" height="200px" style="border:solid black 1px;">
        Your browser does not support canvas element.
      </canvas>

      <button onclick="location.href='../index.php'">ir a inicio</button>            

    </body>
</html>
```

Gracias

Comment: Por favor, proporciónanos algo de código para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: @frikinside, ya he subido el código de mi página, te ha ocurrido algo parecido?
Ayer estuve realizando más pruebas añadiendo un alert a cada evento, y pude observar como los eventos touch no se lanzaban, pero los eventos de ratón como mouseup si.

Comment: He estado haciendo pruebas y no he sido capaz de reproducir el problema. El funcionamiento siempre ha sido el correcto. Parece que es un problema bastante concreto. No es una solución, pero si el problema reside en que el capturador de eventos touch se "rompe" cuando alguien juguetea con la pantalla mientras se carga, no le dejes hacerlo. Bloquea el canvas y lanza el `startup()` más tarde, en el `startup` liberas el canvas y muestras un mensaje de "listo para usar".